# how to make Jquery draggable element append to droppable when dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-clone

Edit: I want the final cloned element to be draggable to any position in the droppable, i do not want it to be sortable.

I'm trying to append my **draggable-clone** element to **droppable** element when it is dropped. when the **draggable** element is inside the  **droppable** element, i want it(the draggable element) to be **draggable** inside the **droppable**. Right now the **draggable-clone** element can be dragged from its position and when it is dropped it becomes undraggable. So please help me in achieving my goal.  Thanks.

here is the code:

```js
$(function () {

    $('#draggable').draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });

    $('#droppable1, #droppable2').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .append(ui.helper.clone(false).css({
                position: 'relative',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px'
            }));
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.well {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.ii{
  float:left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="well">
    <div id="draggable">CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div id="droppable1" class="ii well col-md-3" style="z-index:-1;"></div>
<div id="droppable2" class="ii well col-md-9" style="z-index:-1;"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop a sortable into a sortable (nested divs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348112/drop-a-sortable-into-a-sortable-nested-divs)

Answer (score 1):

The initial element is created as a draggable one on the document ready event, but the new element created when you drop never has this code run on it. It needs to be added to the "drop" event:

```
$('#droppable1, #droppable2').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {        
        $(this)
            .append(ui.helper.clone(false).css({
            position: 'relative',
            left: '0px',
            top: '0px'
        }));
        /* New stuff here: */
        $('.ui-draggable').draggable({
            helper: 'clone'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I want the final cloned element to be draggable to any position in the droppable, i do not want it to be sortable.